# Does compile time depend upon commenting out a portion?

Tags: compiling

I'm currently learning to use Texmaker for preparing a long scientific document. My questions are

> 1. Does the Texmaker take lesser time to compile if some paragraphs are commented out by the percent (%) symbol?

and

> 2. Is there a way to reduce the compilation time when preparing a large document such as a book?

Comment: TeXmaker does no compiling. TeX does it.

Comment: But yes, there is a difference in time compiling a one page document compared to a thousand pages. The difference for one paragraph is not noticible.

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks. Is there a way to reduce the complilation time when preparing a large document such as a book?

Comment: Use `\include` for each chapter and `\includeonly` in your preamble.

Comment: @cfr provided good advice. If you don't know how `\includeonly` and `\include` work, here is a quick guide: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/TeX/includeonly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Commenting the lines out means that the compiler ignores them completely, so it takes less time.

Reducing compile time usually involves steps like (1) making sure your markup is clean and correct, (2) only loading the exact packages you need and no others, and (3) making sure that you're using those packages in the most optimal ways possible (which often requires reading the documentation).

If you're working on a long project like a book, my advice would be to comment out individual sections as you finish them, so you can compile new or work-in-progress sections without doing the entire thing over again.

I should also say that the best way to make a *significant* difference in compile time is to get a faster computer.